# Convergence of sequence of real numbers and (sub)subsequence

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits, metric-spaces

Let $(x_n)_{n\in \mathbb{N}}$ be a sequence of real numbers. A well known result is:

> The sequence $(x_n)_{n\in \mathbb{N}}$ converges to $a\in \mathbb{R}$ if and only if every subsequence $(x_{n_k})_{k\in \mathbb{N}}$ converges to $a\in \mathbb{R}$.

Now, I'm working on an exercise which essentialy asks to prove the following:

> The sequence $(x_n)_{n\in \mathbb{N}}$ converges to $a\in \mathbb{R}$ if and only if for every subsequence $(x_{n_k})_{k\in \mathbb{N}}$ there is a (sub)subsequence $(x_{n_{k_j}})_{j\in \mathbb{N}}$ which converges to $a$.

Now, one direction is trivial. If in fact $(x_n)_{n\in \mathbb{N}}$ converges to $a$, then by the result I've mentioned, every subsequence of $(x_{n})_{n\in \mathbb{N}}$ converges to $a$. Let then $(x_{n_k})_{k\in \mathbb{N}}$ be an arbitrary subsequence. In that case, we know that it is a subsequence of itself, and hence we've found a (sub)subsequence which converges to $a$.

The other way around seems quite complicated for me. The reason is as follows: I must assume that every subsequence $(x_{n_k})_{k\in \mathbb{N}}$ has **a** (sub)subsequence which converges to $a$ and the proof that the original one converges to $a$.

My problem is exactly that "**a**". If it had all (sub)subsequences converging to $a$, then by the result i've mentionted, the subsequence $(x_{n_k})_{k\in \mathbb{N}}$ would converge to $a$. In that case, we would have every subsequence converging to $a$ and the result would follow.

My idea to prove the claim was then:

First remember that a subsequence is the restriction of the original one $x: \mathbb{N}\to \mathbb{R}$ to an infinite subset $\mathbb{N}'\subset \mathbb{N}$. In that case a (sub)subsequence is the restriction of $\tilde{x} = x|\mathbb{N}'$ to an infinite subset $\mathbb{N}''\subset \mathbb{N}$. But since $\tilde{x}$ is the restriction of $x$ to $\mathbb{N}'$ and since $\mathbb{N}''\subset \mathbb{N}'$, the restriction of $\tilde{x}$ to $\mathbb{N}''$ is itself the restriction of $x$ to $\mathbb{N}''$.

In other words, every (sub)subsequence can be viewed as a subsequence of the original one. Considering this, by hypothesis every subsequence has a (sub)subsequence which converges to $a$. But by this argument, this means that we can replace every subsequence with a convergent one. And then we can use the result I stated.

Is my idea correct? Is this really the way to prove the claim? My only doubt is that I need every subsequence converging to $a$ to use the result. In this case I can't see how I can argue that this implies **every** subsequence converges to $a$.

How can I finish this proof?

Comment: Prove the contrapositive!

Comment: Consider that a sequence $ (x_n)_{n \in N}$ converges to $x$ if and only if $ \{n \in N : x_n \not \in (x-d,x+d)\}$  is finite for every $d>0$.

Comment: Thanks @user254665! In that case, each subsequence provides us with one index whose corresponding element is inside such a set. Since this can be done for each subsequence we get an infinite set and the sequence converges. Is this the idea? The proof gets quite simple.

Comment: That's the idea, and it does simplify it a lot.

Answer (score 2):

By contrapositive: Suppose that $(x_n)\not\rightarrow a.$ This means that $\exists\delta>0$ such that $\forall N\in\mathbb N$ there is some natural $n>N$ such that $|x_n-a|\geqslant\delta.$ Now construct a subsequence $(x_{n_k})$ of $(x_n)$ as follows. 
 Let $n_0>0$ be such that $|n_0-a|\geqslant\delta.$ Having chosen $n_0,\ldots,n_k,$ let $n_{k+1}$ be such that $n_{k+1}>n_k$ and $|x_{n_{k+1}}-a|\geqslant\delta.$ Clearly, the subsequence $(x_{n_k})$ does not have a subsequence which converges to $a.$ Consequently, if $(x_n)\not\rightarrow a,$ you will always be able to find a subsequence $(x_{n_k})$ of $(x_n)$ that is *far* from $a.$ Therefore, if every subsequence of $(x_n)$ has a subsequence which converges to $a$ then $(x_n)$ converges to $a.$

Comment: a does not need to be arbitrary. Indeed it is the real number at which every subsequence has a subsubsequence convergent to a. So to prove it, you suppose $a_n$ does not converge to a; then there is a sub sequence that is "away" from a. But then every subsequence of this sequence must be away from a.

Comment: Maybe it is a bit confusing because I should have used "$x$" instead of "$a.$"

Comment: No. The proof is by contradiction and the steatment you are negating is: $a_n$ converges to a. a is not a generic number but is the real number at which every subsequence has a subsubsequence that converges to. Indeed, in the RHS of the original statement,a has to be the same and not depending on the subsequence (in which case the th is clearly false).

Comment: In this case I don't proceed by contradiction but by contrapositive!. You know that a sequence $(x_n)$ of real numbers converges iff $\exists x\in\mathbb R\;\forall\delta>0\;\exists N\in\mathbb N\;\forall n>N\;|x_n-x|<\delta$ so $(x_n)$ diverges iff $ \forall x\in\mathbb R\;\exists\delta>0\;\forall N\in\mathbb N\;\exists n>N\;|x_n-x|\geqslant\delta.$ Is that clear?

Comment: By contrappositive you nagate the statement of the original th. In the original statement a_n converges to a. Therefore, in your proof, you miss that the limit of the main sequence is the same as the limit of the subsubsequence.

Comment: @Kolmo Ok, now I understand what you're saying (sorry, it was late at night when I wrote the answer).

Answer (score 1):

If you are allowed to appeal to point-set topology:

To prove the converse, note that since for every $(x_{n_{k}})$ there is some $(x_{n_{k_{j}}})$ $\to a$ by assumption, by definition $a$ is the limit point of every subsequence of $(x_{n})$, so $\{ x_{n} \} \cup \{ a \}$ is compact. Since $a$ is the unique limit point of $(x_{n})$, it follows that $a$ is the limit of $(x_{n})$.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion @GudsonChou. It becomes indeed very simple in this way, but unfortunatelly this one I've got to do without point-set topology.